# Using triangulation

Tags: programming, geometry, homework

I have been presented with 3 known points and the power densities at those points. I need to use those points to find the location of the actual antenna which is generating the signals.

Power Density is calculated through $PD=(power by antenna)/4*Pi*R^2$

and the inverse law also applies, $PD=\frac{1}{R^2}$, where R is the distance between a known point and the antenna.

What is the best method of apporaching this problem using the Mathematica enviroment? Till now I havent been able to tackle this problem mathematically aswell, as I don't know how it would be done.

I did however come across something, which said plotting circles will be the best, and their intersections will give the coordinates?
how will this work?

This is the module where I have to write the code:

```
Triangulate[measure_] := Module[(* Enter your code here*)]
```

`measure_` contains 3 lists, e.g you would input

```
Triangulate[{{2000,0,1/2},{0,1000,1},{0,0,1/2}}]
```

where first two elements are the x and y coordinates, and the last element is the power density at those points.

Any help to get me started will be appreciated, cause at the moment i dont know how to start or tackle this.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it
too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking 
the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system 
is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to 
accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Comment: Pedantically speaking this is not triangulation, since it doesn't rely on measurement of angles. Instead the solution relies on estimating distance using known signal strength drop over distance; it's called trilateration.

Comment: Are you and this user http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13786/local-variable-naming-symbolic-argument the same person?

Comment: haha no thats not me, but thats someone who is doing the same assignment as me

Comment: Oh god... they are multiplying!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I assume (sorry if I'm being wrong) that this is some kind of homework. So I've written an answer as guidance. You'll have to work out some details.

If your problem is three dimensional, you can write for example:

```
dist[x0_,x1_] := (x0-x1).(x0-x1);
power[x0_,x1_]:= c/dist[x0,x1];
findAnt[{{pow1_,pos1_},{pow2_,pos2_},{pow3_,pos3_}}]:=
                           Solve[power[{x0,y0,z0},pos1]==pow1 &&
                                 power[{x0,y0,z0},pos2]==pow2 &&
                                 power[{x0,y0,z0},pos3]==pow3,{x0,y0,z0}];
```

and find the antenna position for a certain configuration as:

```
findAnt[{{c/2, {1, 0, 0}}, {c/2, {0, 1, 0}}, {c/2, {0, 0, 0}}}]

(*
-> {{x0 -> 1/2, y0 -> 1/2, z0 -> -Sqrt[(3/2)]}, 
    {x0 -> 1/2, y0 -> 1/2, z0 ->  Sqrt[3/2]}}
*)
```

Or, if you want to write the function in more a compact form:

```
findAnt[l:{{_, _}..}]:=Solve[And@@(power[{x0,y0,z0}, #[[2]]] == #[[1]]&/@ l), {x0,y0,z0}];
```

Now you can visualize the possible antenna positions and the measurement points, along with their equipotential surfaces like this:

```
l   = {{c/2, {1, 1, 0}}, {c/4, {0, 1, 1}}, {c/4, {0, 0, 0}}}; 
sol = findAnt[l];

Graphics3D[{PointSize[.05], Blue, Point[l[[All, 2]]], 
                            Red,  Point[{x0, y0, z0} /. sol], 
           Green, Opacity[.2], Specularity[White, 1], 
          {Sphere[{x0,y0,z0} /.sol[[1]], EuclideanDistance[{x0, y0, z0} /. sol[[1]], #]], 
           Sphere[{x0,y0,z0} /.sol[[2]], EuclideanDistance[{x0, y0, z0} /. sol[[2]], #]]}&/@ 
       l[[All, 2]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Edit:

If the power of the antenna is unknown, you can only solve a 2D problem is still easy to solve:

```
(*assuming an antenna of unknown power*)
dist[x0_, x1_]  := (x0 - x1).(x0 - x1);
power[x0_, x1_] := c/dist[x0, x1];
findAnt[l:{{_, _} ..}] := Solve[And@@(power[{x0, y0}, #[[2]]] == #[[1]]&/@ l), {x0, y0, c}];

l   = {{1/2, {1, 0}}, {1/15, {0, 3}}, {1/2, {0, 0}}};
sol = findAnt[l];

Graphics[
 {PointSize[.05], Blue, Point[l[[All, 2]]], Red, Point[{x0, y0} /. sol],
  Green, Dashed, 
 {Circle[{x0, y0}/. sol[[1]], EuclideanDistance[{x0, y0}/. sol[[1]], #]],
  Circle[{x0, y0}/. sol[[2]], EuclideanDistance[{x0, y0}/. sol[[2]], #]]} &/@ l[[All, 2]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And you can show the equipotential curves and the measurement positions for the above solution like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Show[Plot3D[{power[{x0, y0}, {x, y}] /. sol[[1]], 
             power[{x0, y0}, {x, y}] /. sol[[2]]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
             Mesh -> {{1/2, 1/15}}, PlotRange -> {0, .6}, 
             ClippingStyle -> Opacity[0.5],  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
             PlotStyle -> {{Green, Directive[Opacity[.3], Specularity[3]]}, 
                           {Red,   Directive[Opacity[.4], Specularity[3]]}}], 
     Graphics3D[{PointSize[.03], Blue, 
             Point@Join[#, {power[{x0, y0}, #]}] & /@ l[[All, 2]] /. sol[[1]]}]]
```

---

Finally, I want to mention a method that is probably out of the scope of your homework, but can take advantage of the utilization of more than three sensors by using minimization techniques on the potential parameters:

```
model = c/ ((x0 - x)^2 + (y0 - y)^2 + (z0 - z)^2);
(* data is {x, y, z, power} *)
data = {{1, 0, 0, 1/2}, {0, 1, 0, 1/2}, {0, 0, 0, 1/2}};
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, model, {c, x0, y0, z0}, {x, y, z}];
fit["BestFitParameters"]
(*
 -> {c -> 1.25371, x0 -> 0.5, y0 -> 0.5, z0 -> 1.41684}
*)
```

And now you can test that the solution really fits the input data:

```
model /. fit["BestFitParameters"] /. Thread[{x, y, z} -> #] & /@ data[[All, 1 ;; 3]]
(*
->  {0.5, 0.5, 0.5}
*)
```

Comment: Thankyou for the guideline you provided, but im still unsure about how to plot circles, using 3 known points

Comment: THe 3 known points are: 1.{0,0,0,5} 2. {0,1000,1} 3.{2000,0,0.5} where first two are the x and y cordinates, the 3rd element is the powerdensity at that point

Comment: I need to create a module/procedure for this.. so far i have this

Comment: Triangulate[measure_] := 
 Module[{measure1, measure2, measure3, dist1, dist2, dist3, sum},
  measure1 = {measure[[1, 1]], measure[[1, 2]]};
  measure2 = {measure[[2, 1]], measure[[2, 2]]};
  measure3 = {measure [[3, 1]] , measure[[3, 2]]};
  dist1 = EuclideanDistance[measure1, measure2];
  dist2 = EuclideanDistance[measure1, measure3];
  dist3 = EuclideanDistance[measure2, measure3];
  ]

Comment: measure_ is a list that will input 3 points that a user specifies,

Comment: @DanielR Sorry, but I can't see the relation between your code above and the question

Comment: @DanielR With your data the possible solutions are `{{x0 -> 1000, y0 -> 1000}, {x0 -> 1000, y0 -> 3000}}`

Comment: yeah i meant, how do i make a module, where a user inputs 3 lists, with x,y, and power denisty? in mine i calculated the lengths of the sides of triangles taht is formed, and i was hopeing you would assist me as to what i would do next?

Comment: the possible solutions you wrote are correct, how do i get them?

Comment: @DanielR Have you read my answer? Those numbers were calculated using the code under the `(*assuming an antenna of unkown power*)` comment

Comment: I am really sorry, I've been using matlab and I am new to the mathematica software and only have to use it for this question.

Comment: How would the code under (*assuming an antenna of unkown power*) be convered to a mathematica module?

Comment: THis has to be used, Triangulate[measure_] := Module[(* Enter your code here*)]

Comment: @DanielR That is _your_ homework. We usually don't provide direct and complete answers to homework questions here

Comment: For this one time please?

Comment: Pretty pretty please

Comment: Even when the power is unknown, there are solutions. In fact, given three points and three power readings, you can estimate the source location, the power, and even the typical amount of error in the readings.  After all, the data provide nine pieces of information and we only need to get three pieces back out of the procedure.