# Is there a fast way to trilaterate a point?

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I have a point in 2D or 3D space at an unknown coordinate, $p_0$, and I'd like to determine its position using distances from known coordinates $(p_1, p_2, p_3)$.  Beyond using `Reduce`, what is a fast method of doing this in *Mathematica*, particularly for the two-dimensional case?  Is there some built-in function for this?

Also, how can I get an output in coordinate form without any string processing?  For example, to parse the output from `Reduce`, I need to convert the output to a string, infer where the actual coordinate values are, and extract them, which is an awful way to go about doing things.

Here's an implementation with `Solve`:

```
PostOne = {10, 10};
PostTwo = {10, 0};
PostThree = {0, 0};

PointToLocalize = {x0, y0};

D1 = 0;
D2 = 10;
D3 = 200^(1/2);

Solve[EuclideanDistance[PointToLocalize, PostOne] == D1 && 
      EuclideanDistance[PointToLocalize, PostTwo] == D2 && 
      EuclideanDistance[PointToLocalize, PostThree] == D3, {x0, y0}]
```

Now that the string processing issues have been resolved, is `Solve` or `Reduce` really the most efficient way to do this for $10^6$ or $10^7$ or so points?

Comment: Could you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: @s0rce Sure thing.

Comment: @s0rce I've switched Reduce to Solve, and provided specific numeric values.  It works, but I still have to string process the answer, and I feel there might be a better way?

Comment: For the result you can use the following" `{x,y}/.solution`. If you use `Reduce` you can do the following: `{x,y}/.(Rule@@@List@@solution)`.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13745/using-triangulation and https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/VAAWalDJ968

Comment: @Spawn1701D How do I apply what you're suggesting?  Could you give me an example of the command I would feed to Solve?  Nothing I've tried works...

Comment: `soln = Solve[EuclideanDistance[PointToLocalize, PostOne] == D1 && 
       EuclideanDistance[PointToLocalize, PostTwo] == D2 && 
       EuclideanDistance[PointToLocalize, PostThree] == D3, {x0, y0}];
{x,y}/.soln`

Comment: @s0rce Works, got it.

Comment: Is this fast enough?

Comment: @Telomer probably you should switch to `NSolve` or `FindRoot`.

Comment: @Spawn1701D NSolve was a good suggestion.  I've also specified that the domain should be restricted to Real numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In two dimensions, we can reformulate your problem as finding the intersection point of three circles with given centers and radii.

To ease things, you can first form the [radical line](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RadicalLine.html) of two of your three circles, and then find the intersection of that line with the third circle. This will return two solutions, which means we need to do some postprocessing to pick out the one you actually want.

Here's how to go about it:

```
pts = {x, y} /. Solve[{2 (PostTwo - PostOne).{x, y} +
                       PostOne.PostOne - PostTwo.PostTwo == D1^2 - D2^2,
                       #.# &[{x, y} - PostThree] == D3^2}, {x, y}, Reals];

Select[pts, And @@ MapThread[Function[{c, r}, EuclideanDistance[#, c] == r],
                             {{PostOne, PostTwo, PostThree}, {D1, D2, D3}}] &] // First
```

which yields the result `{10, 10}` in your particular case.